# LEMP PHP-FPM not working with nginx on ubuntu 10.04 White Screen

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

I have set up LEMP with the nginx server. I am able to display the html pages but not PHP. I just get an error that this page is unavailable or white blank screen. I am trying to setup wordpress on the Ubuntu 10.04 server. I'm still unable to figure out what the deal is with the php not working.

nginx configuration

```
server {
             listen 80;
             server_name localhost;

             root /var/www/wordpress;
             index index.php index.html index.htm;

             location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
             }

             error_page 404 /404.html;
             error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

             location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/nginx-default;        #/usr/share/nginx/html;
             }

             location ~ \.php$ {
                #try_files $uri =404;
                #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                #fastcgi_index index.php;
                #include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
              }
}

php5-fpm.log
Feb 08 14:04:01.380712 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 3146
Feb 08 14:04:01.387353 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 14:38:43.340483 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 14:38:43.344984 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 14:38:44.388290 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 3334
Feb 08 14:38:44.391049 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 15:03:57.966383 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 15:03:57.971061 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 15:03:59.014873 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 3474
Feb 08 15:03:59.018001 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 15:08:16.355286 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 15:08:16.359873 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 15:08:17.403145 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 3525
Feb 08 15:08:17.406341 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 15:10:25.265253 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 15:10:25.268715 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 15:10:26.311067 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 3570
Feb 08 15:10:26.322278 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 15:31:43.851963 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 15:31:43.856204 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 15:31:44.902028 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 3776
Feb 08 15:31:44.908454 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 15:50:06.496222 [NOTICE] Reloading in progress ...
Feb 08 15:50:06.500402 [NOTICE] reloading: execvp("/usr/bin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/bin/php5-fpm", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php5-fpm.conf"})
Feb 08 15:50:06.561997 [NOTICE] using inherited socket fd=6, "127.0.0.1:9000"
Feb 08 15:50:06.562221 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 4057
Feb 08 15:50:06.564898 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 15:51:53.775527 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 15:51:53.778933 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 15:51:54.822645 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 4095
Feb 08 15:51:54.827625 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections

nginx error.log
2016/02/08 14:01:02 [error] 1433#0: *1 open() "/var/www/nginx-default/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "10.129.3.198", referrer: "http://10.129.3.198/"
2016/02/08 14:17:43 [crit] 3233#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:17:43 [error] 3233#0: *1 open() "/var/www/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:18:04 [crit] 3233#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:18:04 [error] 3233#0: *1 open() "/var/www/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:18:05 [crit] 3233#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:18:05 [error] 3233#0: *1 open() "/var/www/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:18:41 [crit] 3233#0: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:18:41 [error] 3233#0: *7 open() "/var/www/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: cloud59.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:36:36 [warn] 3302#0: conflicting server name "cloud59.net" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2016/02/08 14:36:36 [warn] 3303#0: conflicting server name "cloud59.net" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2016/02/08 14:38:56 [crit] 3323#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:38:56 [error] 3323#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:46:31 [crit] 3382#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:46:31 [error] 3382#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:46:52 [crit] 3382#0: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:46:52 [error] 3382#0: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:49:38 [crit] 3402#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:49:38 [error] 3402#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:55:07 [crit] 3439#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:55:07 [error] 3439#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:56:46 [crit] 3439#0: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 14:56:46 [error] 3439#0: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:04:01 [crit] 3439#0: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:04:01 [error] 3439#0: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:04:02 [crit] 3439#0: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:04:02 [error] 3439#0: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:08:21 [crit] 3514#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:08:31 [crit] 3514#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:10:31 [crit] 3559#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:11:05 [crit] 3559#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:11:07 [crit] 3559#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:11:11 [crit] 3559#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 15:11:47 [crit] 3559#0: *8 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198", referrer: "http://10.129.3.198/readme.html"
2016/02/08 15:29:20 [crit] 3559#0: *12 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
```

Permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data  4096 2016-02-08 15:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root      4096 2016-02-08 14:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   397 2008-05-25 13:33 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        20 2016-02-08 15:35 info.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 15410 2008-12-05 23:47 license.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  9127 2010-04-03 22:57 readme.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  4391 2010-04-19 05:01 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data  4096 2010-06-17 09:05 wp-admin
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 40265 2010-05-26 10:27 wp-app.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   220 2008-10-13 23:22 wp-atom.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   274 2008-05-25 08:50 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  3926 2010-05-06 08:38 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   238 2008-10-13 23:22 wp-commentsrss2.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  3173 2010-05-25 16:47 wp-config-sample.php
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data  4096 2010-06-17 09:05 wp-content
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  1255 2010-03-16 21:39 wp-cron.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   240 2010-04-19 05:03 wp-feed.php
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data  4096 2010-06-17 09:05 wp-includes
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  2002 2010-03-18 01:39 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  2441 2010-02-28 04:19 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 26059 2010-06-01 08:54 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  7774 2010-05-25 19:42 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   487 2009-04-20 14:50 wp-pass.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   218 2008-10-13 23:22 wp-rdf.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   316 2008-05-25 08:50 wp-register.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   220 2008-10-13 23:22 wp-rss2.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   218 2008-10-13 23:22 wp-rss.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  9177 2010-05-02 15:18 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 18685 2010-06-11 13:19 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  3702 2010-02-24 12:13 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 93955 2010-05-03 15:16 xmlrpc.php
root@ubuntu:/var/www/wordpress#
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I cannot test the php version. I tried purging and reinstalling, still no luck. I've noticed that the `pool.d` folder is missing with the `www.conf` file in the `/eth/php5/fpm`. There is php5-`fpm.conf` file, don't know weather thats the same as the `www.conf` that I got missing. If someone could find a solution to what the problem is, that would be great.

Edit:
Additional errors from the recommended tweaks error logs:

```
nginx error.log
2016/02/08 15:11:47 [crit] 3559#0: *8 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198", referrer: "http://10.129.3.198/readme.html"
2016/02/08 15:29:20 [crit] 3559#0: *12 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198"
2016/02/08 18:15:19 [emerg] 4490#0: "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:27
2016/02/08 18:33:49 [emerg] 4538#0: "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:26
2016/02/08 18:35:30 [crit] 4548#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.129.3.105, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.129.3.198", referrer: "http://10.129.3.198/readme.html"
2016/02/08 18:44:08 [emerg] 4642#0: "default_server" parameter can be specified for the default "listen" directive only in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:3

php5-fpm.log
Feb 08 15:50:06.500402 [NOTICE] reloading: execvp("/usr/bin/php5-fpm", {"/usr/bin/php5-fpm", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php5/fpm/php5-fpm.conf"})
Feb 08 15:50:06.561997 [NOTICE] using inherited socket fd=6, "127.0.0.1:9000"
Feb 08 15:50:06.562221 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 4057
Feb 08 15:50:06.564898 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 15:51:53.775527 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 15:51:53.778933 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 15:51:54.822645 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 4095
Feb 08 15:51:54.827625 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 18:35:11.335243 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 18:35:11.340091 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 18:35:12.384908 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 4571
Feb 08 18:35:12.387789 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
Feb 08 18:43:55.545583 [NOTICE] Finishing ...
Feb 08 18:43:55.549643 [NOTICE] exiting, bye-bye!
Feb 08 18:43:56.594919 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 4624
Feb 08 18:43:56.597689 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
```

Comment: What happens when you un-comment these 2 lines: `#fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`?

Comment: @Darren I've tried un-commenting those, still getting "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later." Any ideas what that may be?

Comment: I notice your site isn't listening, try adding this at the beginning of your `server {` tag: `listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;`

Comment: @Darren I'm getting the following message when I made those changes ""default_server" parameter can be specified for the default "listen" directive only in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:3
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"

Answer (score 0):

You should be running this as a socket as well, uncomment these lines

```
#fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

and ensure you have chance the php fpm ini here

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

and ensure that it reads like

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

restart nginx and php-fpm services.

Here is an example of my ubuntu nginx conf here>

server {
        listen 80;

```
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/wph;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;

    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;


    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location / {

             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }
    include /usr/share/nginx/html/wph/nginx.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I have checked those options, I'm still however getting "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later."
I'm not sure what else is wrong.

Comment: are you trying to run this on localhost?

Comment: Also paste you /var/log/nginx/error.log last few entries here. May as well post in some of your php-fpm errors as well so we can get it all fixed.

Comment: I have updated with the most recent logs at the end of the thread. Thanks!

Comment: @Dmitriy `2016/02/08 18:44:08 [emerg] 4642#0: "default_server" parameter can be specified for the default "listen" directive only in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:3` so check the paths you have specified. That latest message indicated you have an issue in paths. Are you trying to access the site from localhost or internal IP. Try both.

Comment: @Dmitriy check my post above. I added my default conf file for a host here.